# Can you add a key to a React JSX Element after it's instantiated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, jsx

Given the following:

```
function generateWrapper(...elements) {
    return (
        <div>
            {...elements}
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    generateWrapper(
        <MyElement name="first" />,
        <MyElement name="second" />,
    ),
    document.getElementById("app"),
);
```

React will rightfully complain that I haven't added a key property to each of the children of the wrapper div. How can I do this? Or is this against the spirit of react development? Thanks for any answers in advance!

PS: Yes there is a similar question I looked at but it seemed to be targeting users not using JSX

PPS: I do realize I can merely add a key to `first` and `second` `MyElement`'s but this is what I'm attempting to avoid

edit: Changing code to better suit my circumstances

Comment: If you render a list, every components needs a key.

Comment: I completely understand why there needs to be a key, and how I could go about doing it during instantiation. I'm just asking if it's possible to do it after instantiation so it could be done once in generateWrapper instead of for every single component

Comment: I normally use `[].map((e, i) => <div key={i}>{e}</div>)`.

Comment: I have also been recommended elsewhere to create a wrapper component for `MyElement` that adds a key to `MyElement`, just to provide all the alternatives I have received for those looking for answers as well

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [React.cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement). You could use that to create and attach the key property inside your `generateWrapper` method.

```
function generateWrapper(...elements) {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        elements.map(element =>
          React.cloneElement(element, { key: 'your-unique-key-here' })
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This seems like exactly what I was looking for. Just wondering, is this method going to continue to be fully supported by the react team? And do you know the performance implications?

Comment: Can't speak on behalf of the React team specifically, but extending the props of a JSX element is a common pattern that probably isn't going away any time soon.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what you have to do if you are adding components that are instantiated somewhere in your code (in my case, on a object with data about different components).
This is fully supported by React team, and it makes sense. Here is the new documentation: https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement